# Specify antialias property in the command line

Tags: java, swing, antialiasing

I remember, not too long ago, somebody post a link on how to specify the global rendering hints to use anti-alias in java.

Unfortunately I can't find the question.

How can I specify the rendering hint to use anti-alias in swing?

Comment: think I found the way to set it globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single Graphics2D:

```
Graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Call that on the `Graphics2D` you are drawing on, and you will have anti-aliasing!!

For global settings:

```
//this SHOULD enable global anti-aliasing
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

**EDIT**
By oreyes:

The first one did it!!!

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4421/imagen1urb.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4421/imagen1urb.png)

vs.

[alt text http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/4089/imagen2i.png](http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/4089/imagen2i.png)

Comment: I guess it will work if used as first line ( or second ) in the main function :P ...

Comment: Wow, what a difference! p.s. You spelled '`Hello`' wrong. `:P`

Comment: Although I think it was another system property, this did the work. The one displayed in the screenshot is: java -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on say.Hello

Comment: Need to be the first line in main() in a large amount of cases. I'd highly encourage it :D